# What is the difference between the different colored dungeon entrances?

Tags: diablo-iii

Sometimes when you see a warp/dungeon area it is a blue light, sometimes it is an orange light. What is the significance (if any) to the colors? Also, are there any colors besides these two?

Comment: Best guess is a boss gate is orange, which requires everyone to accept before continuing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**They signify nothing.** Dungeons, new zones, and boss battles all show in all colors of light (mostly blue, gold, and white). This appears to be more of a design decision (levels with "cool" color schemes use blue, levels with "warm" color schemes use orange/gold).

[image: Warm/Cool colors]<sup>[source](http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm#warm_cool_colors)</sup>

[image: Sacellum of Virtue]
[image: Lonely Dwelling]
[image: Swampy Cellar]
[image: Dark Cultist]

Comment: Very nice answer, I knew it wasn't Boss vs regular becasue countless times I have seen an orange that is certianly not a boss or quest door.

Answer (score 2):

I found this looking for the difference between Gold/Orange doors and Blue doors as they appear on the map. I didn't find the answer here so just in case anyone else stumbles upon this with the same question I had, the difference between the door colors on the map is:

BLUE = Entrance to current area (usually going up). Blue doors go backwards.

GOLD/ORANGE = Doors to the subsequent area (usually going down). Orange doors go onward.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to awnser this but I haven't got the time to find the sources, ill do this tonight. What i have noticed is that the orange light are mostly dungeons, the blue light are passing through sections. Ofcourse you still have dungeons with certain levels, but those dungeons still end forcing you either to teleport out or kill a boss. Also events that happen when you go inside a building get the orange gate.

The blue ones are connected to multiple sections, either dungeons or a path to move forward deeper into the act that you are in.

Comment: In act 3 the Cavern of Frost entrance is blue. Does that punch a hole in your theory?

Comment: @Coomie Hmmm, i must have missread the question. I tought he was talking about the gates on the minimap, either the blue ones or the orange ones. You can seem them in the screenshots from Sean. Those are what i meant. Sean is probably correct about the weather

Comment: Oh, minimap, yeah that seems right. I read it as being about the glow coming from the door.

Answer (score 0):

I found this looking for the difference between Gold/Orange doors and Blue doors as they appear on the map. I didn't find the answer here so just in case anyone else stumbles upon this with the same question I had, the difference between the door colors on the map is:

BLUE = Entrance to current area (usually going up). Blue doors go back.

GOLD/ORANGE = Doors to the subsequent area (usually going down). Gold doors go forward.

Comment: sorry, you're totally wrong. Look even at some screenshots in the accepted answer. Last orange door goes back, both blue doors go forward. The color is only to match the surroundings

Comment: We're talking about 2 different things, Novarg. I'm talking about the map and not about the main game screen. Please read posts carefully. On the last orange door you're referring to, it is Blue on the map in the upper corner. Blue is ALWAYS up and Orange is ALWAYS down. I did find I was wrong about Blue always being back and Orange always being forward. In Diablo 3 down is almost always forward but there are a few exceptions to that. You can actually see the arrows pointing up or down inside the blue and orange flags (respectively) on the map, which I didn't notice until I verified this.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought you were talking about the ingame color, not color on the minimap

Comment: Yeah well that is what the original question was about so you weren't out of your element, you just missed where I said map. You're one of a minority of people not quick to get defensive, not trolling, and classy with your correcting me. You're awesome. Keep that $#!t up.